# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Object?>?' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using block pattern with stream to make api call. I am not getting control inside builder function once i have response from the server. It is giving me an error. Does anyone know solution of it ?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomeWidget(dirty, state: _BannersState#fcb13):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Object?>?'

The relevant error-causing widget was
HomeWidget
lib/routes/routes.dart:8
```

home.dart

```
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BannersState createState() => _BannersState();
}

class _BannersState extends State {
  late BannersBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = BannersBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _bloc.fetchBanners(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot);
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

banners_bloc.dart

```
class BannersBloc {
  late BannerRepository _bannerRepository;
  late StreamController _streamController;

  StreamSink get bannerListSink => _streamController.sink;

  BannersBloc() {
    _streamController = StreamController();
    _bannerRepository = BannerRepository();
    fetchBanners();
  }

  fetchBanners() async {
    bannerListSink.add('Fetching Banners');
    try {
      List banners = await _bannerRepository.getBanners();
      bannerListSink.add(banners);
    } catch (e) {
      bannerListSink.add(e.toString());
      print(e);
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

routes.dart

```
class Routes {
  Routes() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "SabkaBazaar",
      home: new HomeWidget(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomeWidget()
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FutureBuilder<T>` instead of `StreamBuilder<T>`